# What do you call a person who's receiving a service?

Tags: word-request

Example: a social worker goes to anti-social people and tries to bring them back to society.

What do you call the anti-social people? A few words pop up in my mind: clients, customers, patients ... but I think they don't fit this situation very well.

What's a more adequate word?

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/bjsw/article/39/6/1101/1677129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word itself will vary depending on who is delivering the service.

Many professionals who offer services will refer to them as *cases* when talking about the overall situation.  This includes medical professionals, legal professionals, social workers, and others.

> Public defenders are routinely overworked and can have an overwhelming **case** load.

Health care workers (doctors, nurses, physical therapists, psychologists, acupuncturists, etc.) have *patients*.  Some mental health professionals may refer to their patients instead as *clients*, to avoid the implication that there is something medically wrong with them.

> The doctor-**patient** confidentiality protects communications between a patient and his or her doctor from being used against the patient in court.
>
> The renowned psychiatrist primarily was a professor at the medical school, but still occasionally saw **clients** on the side.

Social workers who work with adults have *clients*.  Certain social workers work with *families*.  Others work with *children*.  School counselors work with *students*.  Still others work with *veterans*.  With each, the more specific term is often used in place of *client*.

> When working with **clients**, social workers must maintain clear boundaries to assure professional integrity and responsibility.
>
> Today's school counselors help all **students** in the areas of academic achievement, career, and social/emotional development.

Parole/probation officers have *clients*, but these are also frequently called *offenders*.

> While GPS units can help monitor **offenders**, probation and parole officers must use them in conjunction with other supervision methods.

Police officers serve *the public*, but individual situations that require a police response are *calls*.  Individuals who are arrested by the police are referred to variously as *perpetrators*, *suspects*, or *defendants*, depending on the context, and whether they have been charged with a crime.

> Two Falmouth police officers were wounded responding to a **call** Friday afternoon, and a **suspect** was shot multiple times by the officers.

In your specific example, you can use *client* or *case* depending on the context.

> My **client** has severe anxiety and has trouble talking with anyone he doesn't know.  He's a difficult **case** because sometimes he refuses to even answer the door when I come by.

Answer (score 2):

For social work contexts, where there is a government program or one provided by a non-profit, the word **client** is used in the US once they are being treated.

In some cases, if receiving treatment, patient is used.

And, these clients are **beneficiaries** of these social assistance programs.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say you are receiving a service officially if no framework is being used that provides a definite start/stop to the relationship.

If a social worker is going to random people and trying to get them in a program, probably the most correct and neutral term is *candidate*.

Once in a program they can be considered a *member* or *client*.

It's not uncommon to use the term *customer* outside of a strict commercial setting to communicate that the relationship is expected to be similar.

Comment: . . .and if they are being coerced against their will, *victim* comes to mind. (No matter how good the intentions of the social worker.)